# Is it possible to run a protorpc based service outside of GAE?

Tags: google-app-engine, protorpc

Is it possible to run a protorpc based service outside of GAE?  I see that there is a project hosted at http://code.google.com/p/google-protorpc/ but it seems to depend on the GAE.  The documentation is VERY vague on this point, does anyone have a clear answer?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After messing around with this quite a bit, I have determined that ProtoRPC currently has dependencies on the google app engine.  It is possible to rip the libraries you need out of the sdk, but you will have to change the protorpc source to not import from relative paths.  All in all, it is not worth the hassle, either use the GAE, or don't use protorpc until it can stand on its own.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The source code available at http://code.google.com/p/google-protorpc/source/browse/ includes all of the necessary libraries (minus protobufs itself, which you can download from the Google Developers site), and contains examples both for AppEngine and for a generic WSGI server.

The protorpc library itself is server-agnostic.

Comment: Have you successfully gotten it running outside of GAE?  I see that there is a reference to "google.net.proto" in protobuf.py and I am pretty sure that library is a part of the app engine.

Comment: I believe the posted code assumes GAE imports for ProtocolBuffers, but that is available open-source from https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/ (but no, I haven't run it myself)